# How do I prevent the JQuery effect from repeating?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery effect that delays a particular image for 5seconds and then slides in. But i want when a user reloads the page, the image will not repeat the effect.

Here is my current code:

```
 $(window).load(function () {

    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#alex").show("slide", {
            direction: "down"
        }, 1000);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Use the $.cookie library to store something persistently, and check that value

Comment: Can you give me a code sample?

Comment: Cookies imply having extra data transferred with each request to your server (be it a page, image or anything). I'd suggest using localStorage (with userData fallback for old IE) - [jStorage](https://github.com/andris9/jStorage) handles that just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You keep track of whether you've already done the effect on this page in this browser by using a cookie.  You can do that like this:

```
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}


// only schedule the effect if we haven't already done it
if (!readCookie("effect1")) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        // write a cookie so we don't do this again
        createCookie("effect1", "done");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#alex").show("slide", {
                direction: "down"
            }, 1000);
        }, 3000);
    });
} else {
    // just show it normally
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#alex").show();
    });
}
```

Comment: This may not be what I want. The effects happened once, then when i reloaded it, the image didnt show again. I want a situation where the image will slide in at first, But when you reload the page, the image will continue to be there. It will not disappear to slide in again.

Comment: @AlexUzor - You weren't specific about code needed to run when the page was reloaded.  I guessed and did a normal `.show()` on `#alex`, but you can adapt that code to whatever you need.  Setting the cookie allows you to control what happens the first time vs. other times.